# Which book was this: it involved common genetic engineering, supermen, fourth dimensional mutants?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I've been wracking my mind to track down a book I read in 1981 or so.
What I remember: It was set in the nearish future and genetic engineering was common.  Some people had super or even godlike powers.  At least one lived in a fourth dimension, had worshippers, and manifested as a giant hand reaching from a hole in space (?).  I think at least one character was a woman with super strength, though I may be conflating her with a similar character from Zelazny's *[Creatures of Light and Darkness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creatures_of_Light_and_Darkness)*.

Comment: I don't recognize the book; but try Booksleuth: http://forums.abebooks.com/abesleuthcom -- they're really good at finding those books you've lost.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of that site.  I'll ask there, and post the answer here if I get one.

Answer (score 1):

By any chance... could it be Frank Herberts' *The Godmakers*?

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer, why you think its a match?

Comment: Well it has been a while since I read the book but one of the things i remember most about the book was dealing with the main protagonist actually becoming a god at the end of the book.

Comment: I don't recall this book as being by a well-known author like Herbert.  I'll look for a synopsis of 'The Godmakers' in a few hours and let you know.

Comment: I don't think "The Godmakers" was it.  I haven't read it, but reading the plot summary doesn't ring any bells.  Thanks for the suggestion!